# How to insert child nodes into existing parent node in one to many relationship with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, one-to-many

I have two classes, User and Document with relation of One (User) - Many (Documents) relationship.
My application use Nodejs with Sequelize, and my models like this:

**Document Model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Document = sequelize.define( "documents", {
    pubmedID: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    documentLink: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER, // 0: not start, 1: Working, 2: Waiting, 3:Approved
      allowNull:false
    },
    active: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {timestamps: true}, )
  return Document
}
```

**User model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define( "users", {
     userName: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         allowNull: false
     },
     email: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         unique: true,
         isEmail: true, //checks for email format
         allowNull: false
     },
     password: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         allowNull: false
     },
     role: {
         type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     allowNull:false
     },
     active: {
         type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
         allowNull: false
     }
   }, {timestamps: true}, )
   return User
}
```

In my index.js of Model, I created relationships:

```
db.users.hasMany(db.documents, {foreignKey: 'userName'});
db.documents.belongsTo(db.users, {foreignKey: 'userName'});
```

Then, in my Controller, my code for insert Documents to current login users, using user'username

```
var pubmedID = element.id;
var title = element.passages[0].text;
var userName = String(req.body.userName);
const docData = {
            pubmedID: pubmedID,
            title:title,
            documentLink: filename,
            status: 0,
            active: true,
            userName: userName,
          };  
createdDocument = Document.create(docData)
```

however, in my database, the column userName was created with INT datatype, while it should be string and so that my INSERT not working.
I also try to user userid for instead of using userName, however, in my INSERT function, I cannot get the userID from the user, because it was not defined as a field in my User model, it is auto-increased field in database.
I think my approach is not correct, could you please help to show me how to do it

I search my example from Sequilize user guide, but most of them build the whole data include Parent and child and once and input both of them in to database, while I only need to insert Documents as child nodes, and the parent node (User) is already existed.